# Netbeans : Library's are not included in the project folder

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to package a netbeans project up as a zip so I can send it around a few developers. However I have built a library as another project and included it as a library using the netbeans "add project" option.

However....

the libray is never added to the project folder... is there a setting I can change that include the jar so other developer can unzip the project and use "out of the box"?

Cheers

Comment: Short answer is no. The long answer is use Maven. You will need to include all dependent libraries, either as additional MetBeans packages or as complied binaries, I'd add them into a lib directory within the Netbeans project folder personally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need:

1. Right click on your project -> **`Properties`**
2. **`Libraries`** -> **`Libraries Folder`** -> **`Browse`**
3. Select the folder *`[Step 1]`* (eg. insert `./lib` - directory is created if not existing) -> Next
4. Set the *Actions* as you need *`[Step 2]`*, maybe the default action ("*Use Existing ...*") is already what you need
5. **`Finish`**

This will ...

- Create a common Lib directory in your project folder
- If you *clean & build* your project there will be a lib folder in the dist directory which contains all your libraries of the project

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans will package the jar in a lib folder only if the project is a java application project. i.e. it should be a java project with a class having main method. It should be specified in the Run category of the Project Properties. If you run the clean and build, the dist folder will have the application jar and the library will be added as a jar under the lib folder. The contents of the dist folder could then be zipped and shared with other developers. They should be able to execute it out of the box. 
Note: The manifest file of the application jar will have a class path entry to the library.

If you need the the same behaviour for java projects that are not applications, modify the ant scripts.